# Generate image with GPUImagePerlinNoiseFilter

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, gpuimage

I'm new in [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). I want to create a noisy background at given size. Seems like I should use GPUImagePerlinNoiseFilter, but I have no idea how to **generate** an image.

```
let noiseFilter = GPUImagePerlinNoiseFilter()
noiseFilter.colorStart = GPUVector4(1, 1, 1, 0)
noiseFilter.colorStart = GPUVector4(1, 1, 1, 1)
noiseFilter.scale = 0.5
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Have you checked Processing a still image chapter of documentation?

Comment: Y, but I have no input image to process.

Comment: You could create blank image and use filter on it.

Comment: I've already done this but it looks redundant.

Comment: Add picture with problem to your question. Usually filters applied to something so you need initial data anyway.

Comment: I need to generate noise like this: http://noisetexturegenerator.com/ No input image provided. Thank you for your attention anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In provided noise generator they use input image too (you set size and color), so I think I'm correct.
Here is my solution:

```
import UIKit

import GPUImage

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 100))
        imageView.image = createNoiseImage(CGSizeMake(100, 100), color: UIColor.whiteColor())
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    private func createNoiseImage(size: CGSize, color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        let filter = GPUImagePerlinNoiseFilter()
        return filter.imageByFilteringImage(image)
    }
}
```

With default filter parameters it produces this:

[image]